# Good To Use Classes to Create Dummy Data for Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I am trying to do some unit tests and I need dummy data. Some of this data I need to have specific values, other will be just random.

I have for instance a "CreateProduct" method in my Service Layer and I am wondering if it is a good idea to use such methods instead of making a product by hand in my unit tests.

On the surface this seems like a good idea but I am worried maybe I will need to mocking or something to successfully get through that method.

The CreateProduct will try to save the product to the database but I have already a flag that will stop the save happening(used for unit of work scenario encase of rollbacks).

I am using EF 6-rc1 and mocking up the DataContext with moq and I was going to use AutoFixture but it does not work out of box for this secnario and I am starting to feel I am taking too much new tools on at once so maybe I should just do it manually for now.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Do you have code sample on what you trying to achieve? You mentioned about you need dummy data, and the next paragraph your question is about stubbing out a factory method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are doing without a code example, but I sometimes use [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/rally25rs/1492134) of an `IDataSet` that uses a `List` in memory. Typical usage would be something like:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace EFMock
{
    internal interface IDataContext
    {
        IDbSet<DataItem> DataItems { get; set; }
    }

    class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
    {
        public IDbSet<DataItem> DataItems{ get; set; }
    }

    class DataItem
    {
        public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
    }

    /* ----------- */

    class DataUsage
    {
        public int DoSomething(IDataContext dataContext)
        {
            return dataContext.DataItems.Sum(x => x.SomeNumber);
        }
    }

    /* ----------- */

    [TestFixture]
    class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            var fakeDataItems = new [] {
                new DataItem { SomeNumber = 1, SomeString = "One" },
                new DataItem { SomeNumber = 2, SomeString = "Two" }};

            var mockDataContext = new Mock<IDataContext>();
            mockDataContext.SetupGet(x => x.DataItems).Returns(new FakeDbSet<DataItem>(fakeDataItems));

            var dataUsage = new DataUsage();
            var result = dataUsage.DoSomething(mockDataContext.Object);

            Assert.AreEqual(2, result);
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a NuGet package named "FakeO" that you can use to create some fake objects, where some data is a specific value and some is random:

```
var fakeDataItems = FakeO.Create.Fake<DataItem>(10, // create an IEnumerable of 10 items
    x => x.SomeNumber = FakeO.Number.Next(),        // set to a random number
    x => x.SomeString = "Always This String");      // set to a specific string
```

---

One thing to keep in mind with this kind of testing is that using an `IQueryable` against a `List` will use Linq2Objects and not Linq2Entities, so results of some Linq queries will be different.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Unit Test something, you'll just want to test the **unit**. If you use a method in the servicelayer to generate some fake data, the unit test is not only testing the unit under test, but also the method in the service layer.

So the answer to your question: no, it is not a good idea to use the service layer to dummy data